# Travelling from PHL to BOS to LHR, do I need security check at BOS again?

Tags: airport-security, british-airways, american-airlines, connecting-flights, bos

I am travelling from Philadelphia to New Delhi. The flight is with American Airlines, from Philadelphia to Boston to London To New Delhi.

Do I need to come out land-side at Boston airport, for security check? My flight from Boston to London is a code-share with British Airways.

Comment: In my experience, no, you will not have to, but my relevant experience is not recent.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely yes. American Airlines arrives into terminal B and British Airways departs terminal E. There is no airside connection between the terminals.